# How to call postgres function in Django with OUT parameter

Tags: django, postgresql

I've created a simple function in postgres as below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_django(p_a int, p_b int, out p_cursor  refcursor, out p_int int)
RETURNS record AS
$BODY$
begin

p_cursor := 'test_cursor';

open p_cursor for
select id, name, des from test;

p_int := 100;

END
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I want to call this function via Django and get 2 OUT parameters. one is cursor and one is INTEGER;

Is there any way to pre-register those parameters like Java? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I find a solution.

```
>>> with transaction.atomic(), connection.cursor() as cur:  
...   cur.execute('''select test_django(1,2)''')
...   a = cur.fetchone()
...   a
...   cur.execute('fetch all from test_cursor')
...   cur.fetchall()
... 
('(test_cursor,100)',)
[(2, 'aa', 'aaaaa'), (3, 'aabb', 'aaaaabbb')]
```

I can fetch the cursor well but the INTEGER parameter is actually inside a String , it's so weird...

Is there any good way to resolve this?